# How to edit values in Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
var airports : [String:String] = ["DXB" : "dubai international airport", "LHR" : "heathrow international airport"]

for (airportCode,airportName) in airports
{
airportName = airportName.capitalized
}
```

so I need to capitalize all values for example but I get the error

> "Cannot assign to value: airportName is a let constant

Answer (score 1):

Just add `var` in your for loop

```
var airports : [String:String] = ["DXB" : "dubai international airport", "LHR" : "heathrow international airport"]

for (var airportCode,var airportName) in airports
{
airportName = airportName.capitalized
airports[airportCode] = airportName
}
```

Comment: OK, but now `var` is actually not necessary.

Comment: Yes. It can be done simply by `airports[airportCode] = airportName.capitalized`

Answer (score 0):

Index variables are constants by definition. You can do

```
var airports = ["DXB" : "dubai international airport", "LHR" : "heathrow international airport"]
for (airportCode, airportName) in airports
{
    airports[airportCode] = airportName.capitalized
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but it works and is straightforward:

```
let keys = airports.keys
for key in keys {
    airports[key] = airports[key]!.capitalized
}
```

You first get all the keys in the dictionary and for each key, set the corresponding value.